# jquery mobile, use android hardware back button to close a panel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I created a panel using jqm, and I'd like to be able to use the andoird phones back button to close it when it's open.

For now, when the panel is open and I use the back button, it goes to the previous page, instead of only closing the panel.

Any idea how to do this ?
Here's my html page with the panel :

```
<div id="welcome-page" data-role="page">    
    <a data-role="button" id="open-panel" data-theme="a">Enquiries</a>
</div>
```

Here's the structure of my js file for the panel :

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#welcome-page', function(){                
    $('<div>').attr({'id':'mypanel','data-role':'panel','data-position':'right','data-display':'overlay'}).appendTo($(this));
    $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
        $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");
        populateContactForm('args');
        ...
    }); 
    $(document).on('change', '#mypanel input[type=radio]', function(){ 
    ...
    });
});


$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {   
  $(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#mypanel').panel("close");
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can capture hardware back button as below in javascript:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    // Prevent default (disable the back button behavior)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Your code to close panel or show another page or whatever...
    $( '#mypanel' ).panel( "close" );
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks but I don't know where to put it in my js file. Should I put it within the `$(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){` ? or just in the  `$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#welcome-page', function(){ ` ? I tried both and it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: you can create document **ready** event and then add my code inside it for best practice.

Comment: Isn't it best practive to use page events instead of document ready with jqm ? I would like this override to be active only when the panel is open.

Comment: you can check it when back button is press

Comment: What do you mean. Please I need the specific location where to put this js snippet. thanks. I tried into the on click, into the on pagebeforecreate, and out, and it doesn't work.

Comment: How can I check this without using `alert` which doesn't seem to work on android?

Comment: is it possible to test this in a js fiddle, with the android back button?

Comment: no you can not check in jsfiddle. but if you want to test you can write some message in your page i.e. $("div").html("back button clicked");

Comment: Thanks. Ok I see, even with this to test, I can't capture the back button. I am trying this snippet I added in the question but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: moreover, when I test my app on my laptop's firefox, the ESC key (which keycode is also 27) closes the panel, whereas the back button on android does not...

Comment: Refer this link may be help to you : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Comment: key 27 is escape, this is not the same as the android back button.